# vxworks :create a file with specific size and rendom data

Tags: vxworks

How can I create a file with rendom data but with specific size in vxworks?
I need to fill a very big memory but only with files, there is a good why to do that? (except copy files that already exist over and over again)

Answer (score 0):

Do this the same way you would on any system.

- Create a file (creat or open), at the location you want.
- Create some random data using the normal random functions.
- Write that to the file (write).
  .. Repeat the random data step and write step until the file is as big as you need it.
- Close the file (close).

How much random data, and how you create that data will dictate how long it will take to get the file size you want.